# How can I train my dog to behave for grooming?

Tags: dogs, behavior, grooming

My 2-year-old Yorkshire Terrier really hates to be groomed, and with the amount of hair Yorkies have, this is not good.  To my knowledge, he hasn't had a bad past with groomers, unless it happened before we adopted him at 6 weeks.  When I try to comb him with a wide-tooth comb, he will bite the comb, squirm, and I am unable to finish combing him.  I am unable to obtain the supplies to groom him properly, so I take him to a groomer about once a month.  I would like him to behave for the groomers, but am unsure how to "train" him to do this.

How can I train my dog to behave during grooming?

Comment: Worth noting that professional groomers have had some practice at handling less willing dogs.  You might want to ask them about it.

Answer (score 3):

If you're doing it yourself, you have to have more patience and they will eventually give up the fight.

If you're taking it to a groomer, find a good one, then try having someone other than yourself bring the dog. It's a weird thing, but dogs (like kids) tend to be more dramatic when their "parents" are in the room.